# Javascript array with index in declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running a js code and in some part of it there is a definition of an array which I don't get what it means , it looks like this :

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[myNum] = new Array();
myArray[myNum].push(value1);
```

I don't get why there is an index of the array at the second line , is it a two dimensional array ? I'll appreciate if you can help me with this. 
 thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

Creates an array.

```
myArray[myNum] = new Array();
```

Creates an array in `myArray`'s `myNum` index.

```
myArray[myNum].push(value1);
```

Stores `valuea1` into the array (adds the element at the last, in this case at `0`-th index) stored in `myArray[myNum]`.

Yes, your assumption is right - after the execution of the three statements a two dimensional array is created, which looks something like this -

```
[....., [value1], ......]  // the inner array is stored at "myNum" index
```

To access `value1`, you can now do -

```
myArray[myNum][0];
```

See the [doc for push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 1):

This code just creates an array with an array at index `myNum`. Lets break the code down.

```
var myArray = new Array();
//Create a new array
myArray[myNum] = new Array();
//At index 'myNum' which is a variable presumably holding an index - create a new array
myArray[myNum].push(value1);
//push variable `value1` to the new array at index myNum of myArray.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain your code....

**Explanation:**

```
var myArray = new Array();   // (1)
myArray[myNum] = new Array();  // (2)
myArray[myNum].push(value1);  // (3)
```

**(1)** This creates a new empty array . It could be 1D, 2D, 3D. Currently it has nothing. At this point you array should look like this..

```
myArray= [];
```

**(2)** This creates another empty Array in *"myArray"* at index *"myNum"*. Let us assume myNum=5;

So

```
myArray[5] = new Array();
```

Will give

```
myArray =[[]];
```

**(3)** This will push value1 into myArray at index *"myNum"*. Let us again assume myNum=5 and value1 = 1,2,3;

So

```
myArray[5].push(1,2,3);
```

Will give

```
myArray=[[1,2,3]]
```

[DEMO IN A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ffTV7/)